# I'can't access to the dockerized react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am trying to run a React app on a Docker container, so I built the image and then ran the container. However, I cannot reach the app.

**OS** Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
firewall inactive **sudo ufw status** :

```
Status: inactive
```

**Dockerfile** :

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /entreprise

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**docker ps** output :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
3a8edf622b9d   react-entreprise:v1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:5173->5173/tcp, :::5173->5173/tcp   entrepriseFN
```

**docker logs 3a8edf622b9d** output :

```
> entreprise@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v4.2.1  ready in 1011 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
```

I tried

- rebuilding the image
- rerunning the container
- checking the firewall
- and mapping the port to another port

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, vite *binds* to localhost. That means that your app will only accept connections from localhost. In a container, localhost is the container itself, so your app refuses to accept connections from outside the container.

To fix it, you need to open your package.json file and change the line with the `dev` script from

```
"dev": "vite",
```

to

```
"dev": "vite --host 0.0.0.0",
```

That will make vite bind to 0.0.0.0 and accept connections from outside the container.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, Thank you very much for your effort.